# C# System.Diagnostics.Process how to handle multiple batch files

Tags: c#, wpf, batch-file, tomcat

I'm trying to start tomcat from my c# wpf app using the startup.bat and after deploying the war files, I want to close it. Here is how I've been doing it and it seemed to work fine.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = Tomcat_DIR_tbox.Text + @"\bin\startup.bat";
            proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Tomcat_DIR_tbox.Text + @"\bin\";
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.Start();
            // do some bla bla
            //Close Tomcat
            proc.StartInfo.Filename = Tomcat_DIR_tbox.Text + @"\bin\shutdown.bat";
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
```

Now I've been thinking that although it works, it's not quite right ? the Tomcat application started never stops unless I tell it to, it feels wrong to use the same process to also shut it down ?

What I've down now is something like this : Kept the process for starting up tomcat, and created another one which calls for the shutdown:

```
//Close tomcat            
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc_shutdown = new System.Diagnostics.Process();               
            proc_shutdown.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Tomcat_DIR_tbox.Text + @"\bin\";
            proc_shutdown.StartInfo.FileName = Tomcat_DIR_tbox.Text + @"\bin\shutdown.bat";
            proc_shutdown.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc_shutdown.Start();
            proc_shutdown.WaitForExit();
```

The only thing I don't like about this method is that it brings a message which asks me if I allow the shutdown.bat to be called from my application, which I can uncheck "Don't ask me again for this file" but I still don't like the user experience it provides.

I also tried calling directly proc.Close() instead of doing proc.Filename = path_to_shutdown and proc.Start(), but it seemed to hang up my application and never close tomcat.

So what is the best way to start tomcat, do some stuff and then close it up ? Thanks , Razvan.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my observation, what you are doing is fine to start and stop the tomcat server from WPF application. But, if you want to hide the security warning, Then Open Internet Explorer Go to Tools -> Internet Options and then select "security" tab from there select (Custom level..).. In that in the Miscellaneous group there will be option called

"Launching Applications and Unsafe files" -> Select Enable Radio button. Then it won't show you the "allow the shutdown.bat" popup.

Hope, it helps.